Why the "amps" in hive-site.xml can not be identified when used the "schematool -initSchema"
After configuring Hive and mysql, I hope to upgrade the metadata through the schematool tool that comes with Hive. When I enter the upgrade instructions, the following error is displayed. I also used the & escape character in hive-site.xml, but still Errors will occur.
The content of hive-site.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hive</value>
    <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>hive</value>
    <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
</configuration>

and the error:
enter image description here
I tried to delete the useSSL content after &, but another error occurred. I don't have any other ideas because I'm still in the beginner stage.

Use &amp; in place of & in XML.
See also

What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?
Ampersand in URL makes XML not well formed?

